# How do you text HTML tags on the webpage?

Tags: html

I am making a program, and I want to text an HTML tag on the webpage. Is there a way for me to display an HTML tag as text instead of it actually being an HTML tag?

Comment: You mean like `&gt;span&lt;Some content&gt;/span&lt;`?

Comment: You could HTML encode it, which would replace "special" characters (characters HTML parsing engines consider to be non-text) with codes representing those characters.  How you do that depends on your program, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape your HTML using `&lt; TAGNAME &gt;` to display < TAGNAME >

Answer (score 1):

Use `&lt;` and `&gt;` instead of `<` and `>` respectively.